# Create a new object from a collection of objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC web app using jQuery. I bring in a collection of objects. For simplicity, my object is Dog and has a property dogName. The collection I bring to my web page from my controller is

```
...
  List<Dog> 
...
```

with the dog names filled in. In jQuery can I create an empty Dog object from the objects in the collection? The new object will not be added to the collection.

```
...

    function getDogs() {
    var myUrl = ' /Canine/getDogs/ ';
    $.post(myUrl, null, function (data) { landGetDogs(data); }, 'json');
    }

   var myDogs = null
   var dog = null

    function landGetDogs(x){
    //set my collection to the myDogs variable
    myDogs = x
    // now I want to create an empty Dog and set it to my var dog

   }

...
```

Edited to show a complete example.

My class Dog

```
public class Dog
{
    public string dogName { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method

```
 public ActionResult getDogs()
    {
        List<Dog> myList = new List<Dog>();

        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.dogName = "Spot";
        myList.Add(d);

        d = new Dog();
        d.dogName = "Rudy";
        myList.Add(d);

        return Json(d);
    }
```

In my web page

```
function getDogs() {

    var myUrl = '/Canine/getDogs/'
    $.post(myUrl, null, landDogs, 'json');

}

 var myDogs = null;
function landDogs(x) {

   myDogs = x;

     
}
```

Now I have a collection of Dogs. My question is can I create a new empty Dog from a Dog object in the collection?

Comment: Are you trying to do it without creating a constructor function that handles it manually?

Comment: FYI, you can eliminate the anonymous function in your `$.post` call, like this: `$.post(myUrl, null, landGetDogs, 'json');`

Comment: I could do it in a constructor but I'm wondering if I can do it in jquery/javascript?. Thanks for the FYI on simplifying my $.post!

Comment: myDogs = x;
 var empty = {dog_field1: '',field2: '' ....};
myDogs.push(empty);

Comment: @Raf jQuery doesn't have anything to help, but by "constructor", I meant a JavaScript function. It would probably help clarify your question if you showed an example of the data you're receiving, and specifically what you want to do. Just a small but complete example that generally represents the problem would do.